# Как поймать событие отправки формы из дочернего окна на другом домене?

Tags: javascript, cors, jsonp

Моя цель перезагрузить страничку после авторизации пользователя. Если окошко просто закрыто без отправки формы, то перезагружать не надо. В окошке другой сайт (другой домен), на котором уже реализован функционал межсайтовой авторизации методам передачи куков. Все уже работает, но бесит один костыль:

```
...
function childListener() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (accountsWindow.closed) {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            childListener();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
childListener();
```

то есть я опрашиваю статус модального окна каждую секунду, что бы перезагрузить страницу. Естественно перезагружаю в любом случае не зависимо от того была ли отправлена форма или просто закрыто крестиком.

на прямое обращение через **window.opener** даже с **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** браузер отвечает, ошибкой в консоли, что дескать заблокировано (проверял в хроме и в фф).

Не хотелось бы прикручивать к проекту большие библиотеки ради исправления такого маленького костыля, потому может кто-то подскажет простой и лаконичный способ решения проблемы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `window.postMessage` -- видимо, то, что нужно ......... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage  ....... https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: window.postMessage решил проблему.

Answer (score 0):

в окне родителе (window.opener):

```
function listener(event) {
if (event.origin != 'https://accounts.factor.local') {
    return;
}
if(event.data == 'event.data'){
    location.reload();
}...
```

в дочернем окне:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var win = window.opener;
    win.postMessage("event.data", '*');

    self.close();
}, 1000);
```